# Curl and divergence operators

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

I'm wondering if there's a TeX package where I could find a proper command to type curl and divergence in equations.
Any help?
Cheers,
Riccardo

Comment: `\DeclareMathOperator{\Curl}{curl}` and `\DeclareMathOperator{\Div}{div}` and then `\Curl f` and `\Div f` will do in math mode.

Comment: Grazie mille Professore! (Ho seguito il suo corso di LaTeX a Verona)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Benvenuto! A knock at my door could have been easier. `;-)`

Comment: I know, but I moved to Trento for my master in Math! Thank you again :-)